# Help with six cylinder out of a trailblazer.05 into a 06

Tags: engine, chevrolet, trailblazer

I would like to know if I can just drop in. Can't find anything on how to tell what reluctor wheel is in the motors. Need help due to the fact that I took on a project and don't have a lot of  knowledge when it comes to newer cars. Plus wife is not happy!

Answer (score 1):

While externally the '05 would fit in the '06 (same dimensions, bolt-up, etc), my understanding is the internals are different. In '06 they "redid" the engine internally, which means the 05 will not work for you. You can use the engine out of an 07, but you'd need to swap your '06 injectors into the other engine.

Comment: So I can't use it even if I change reluctor wheel ?

Comment: That is my understanding. The differences are too major.

Comment: @RobAdado - If what I'm reading is correct, the only way to change out the reluctor wheel is to change out the crank shaft. The 06-07 used the 24x wheel (standard LS Gen-III) and the 08-09 used the 58x wheel (Gen-IV). The 05 and before used a 7x reluctor wheel. The relearn sequence won't do the trick for you either.